# How to navigate to previous page using device back button - Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, device, back-button

When I press the device back button, it navigate to the homepage but not to the previous page.

I would like  to know how to  navigate to the previous page using the the device back button.

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me how you're navigating to the current page from your previous page? It appears to me that you must be using replacement somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Materialapp widget problem.

I solved the problem by deleting the  Materialapp widget that was in one of the pages.

Comment: What a star! thanks a lot. Yes it was the same for me, I replaced Materialapp widget with direct Scaffold and all sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You might have used `Navigator.pushReplacement` which destroys the previous page and creates the new page.However if you use `Navigator.push` pressing the back button will navigate you to the previous screen.

Example:

```
Container(
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(child: Text("Next page"),onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2(),)); // back button will navigate to previous screen
            //Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2(),)); //  back button will not navigate to previous page
          },),),),
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the previous navigation was not saved in the route stack.

What you should do is this:

**Widget A**

```
Navigator.push(context, WidgetB());
```

Inside **Widget B**, press the device button and you will return to widget A.

*It is important that in widget A you are not using replacement or another that removes widget A from the stack.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

or

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/routeName');
```